# How to build a counter in Simulink which counts impulses with given length?

Tags: matlab, counter, simulink

I would like to model railway interlocking. The counter recieves impulses with the following parameters:

- length of signal:260 ms
- short break:130 ms
- long break: 520 ms

Here is the signal generator:

[image]

These are the block paramaters:
Sine:
[image]

Impulse generator:
[image]

4-impulses:

[image]

And this is the sign in which I would like to count the impulses:

[image]

In the example I would like to count 4 impulses in one period because we know that one period is 1950 ms.

Comment: This is very similar to a question I commented on a few days ago although I can't find it... That question had more information about the blocks you're using I think? It appears you've fixed that half-pulse issue, great! Can you provide more details here on what "I would like to count 4 impulses" means? Should the counter cycle 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...? Or should it count up to 4 and hold? How are you defining the pulses you want to count? Is it not a function of the input block setup so you have the answer up front anyway?

Comment: Yes,I would like to hold this number.

Comment: So just time from the last point when `abs(signal)>threshold` for some threshold, which indicates the signal is active, and if it's over the duration of your short pause then increment the counter. If you've passed the threshold for the long pause then stop incrementing forever

Comment: Is there a block for it or should I  solve it in MATLAB Function block?

Comment: I think you could do it with a combination of `clock`, `switch`, `memory`, and `relational operator` blocks if there's not something more complete for timing in the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels fairly convoluted, but it's hopefully easy to follow and adapt.

Essentially you can check how long the pauses are, and if that pause duration satisfies your criteria then increment a counter.

Comment groups added for what each group of blocks is doing, might be possible to simplify this using some latched timers but I didn't explore the block library so this uses all very fundamental blocks.

Diagram (click to enlarge)

[image]

Scope:

[image: scope]

Comment: Thank you so much!What are the switch's parameters?

Comment: Just the default settings for a switch except the condition is `~=0`, so the top input is when switch signal is true and the bottom input when false.

Comment: How to modify it so it become a counter cycle?(1,2,3,4)